# Hardcoding Conditional Formatting Icons in Excel for HTML Export

Tags: html, vba, excel

I'm looking to export an Excel file into HTML format and keep the same formatting when this is done. I'm aware of general difficulties when dealing with Excel and HTML exporting, but for a variety of reasons this is what we are pursuing.

I'm constrained to Microsoft Excel 2010. When I export to HTML, every aspect of the formatting goes through *except for* conditionally formatted icons (in this case the little green circle / yellow caution sign). The way we are reporting makes having these icons crucial. Is there an easy way (in VBA or otherwise) to "hardcode" the icons in order to make them appear in the HTML export? That is, is there an easy way to place an image at a certain size in a certain cell conditionally using a script before something is exported?

Alternatively, if there is a way to get conditionally formatted icons to work in HTML exports that would be a great solution.

Comment: You'll have to capture the result of the conditional formatting and insert the icons as an img in the HTML.

Comment: @jbarker2160 Is there a way to do that within Excel (e.g. VBA/Macro) without having to go into the HTML after the fact? Or is there a way to do so in the HTML in an automated fashion? I don't think the conditional formatting leaves anything behind in the HTML file that I could use to detect where a particular icon goes.

Comment: You could insert an image next to the cells, but that is notoriously difficult to display correctly with HTML.  The best thing to do would be to have a macro make your HTML for you.  Then you can insert the appropriate tags at the correct time.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. How did you solve it?